# Using Vim's "autocorrect" feature

Tags: vim

If I create mappings in vim for autocorrecting ("teh" to "the"), how will it affect Vim's speed?

Also, if I were to actually want to type "teh" how would I do it without vim autocorrecting it?

Answer (score 2):

Please use *abbreviations*, not *mappings* for those. The former will only activate once the entire word is typed (like in word processors), and it does not have the side effect of suppressing additional characters until the mapping is fulfilled or does not match:

```
:ia teh the
```

You won't notice a delay, and it should be possible to define hundreds, if not thousands of those without noticing.

To avoid the abbreviation in insert mode: Type part of the abbreviation, exit insert mode with `<Esc>`, re-enter insert mode with `a` and type the rest.  Or type `<C-V>` before the character after the abbreviation.

All details at `:help abbreviations`.

Comment: I suspect that OP didn't mean "mappings" in a technical sense. (I.e., that they thought of `ia` as a mapping, in a sense.) In any case, though, it's a useful clarification.

Answer (score 1):

1. Speed difference will be Negligible.
2. You can use `<C-C>` to exit insert mode this will stop vim from trying to change the abbreviation or you can type it out and put a space or something in it and then go delete that character after words.

Answer (score 0):

I have over 44,000 abbreviations that are loaded asynchronously every time I start vim. A delay only happens while inserting a new abbreviation, and this delay increases with the length of the list of existing abbreviations. Once added, there is no difference in speed at all while in insert mode compared to having no abbreviations whatsoever.

As the other answers mentioned, use `<C-C>` or `<C-V>` after typing a word to avoid automatically replacing it. Using `<C-V>` keeps you in insert mode while `<C-C>` returns to normal mode.